# How to resolve ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED in puppeteer connection while calling page.goto

Tags: javascript, proxy, puppeteer, tor

[Image of error I receive while the code executes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB9Kd.png)

Here is the code I am using :

proxy.js -

```
class Proxy
{
    static create() {
     return new Proxy();
   }
   this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       args: [`--proxy-server=socks5:127.0.0.1:9150`, "--no-sandbox",
      ],
     });
    async newPage(newBrowser = false) {
     /* Ensure a browser instance is present */
     if (!this.browser) {
       await this.launchNewBrowser();
     }
 
     /* Close all other pages/tabs */
     await this.closePages();
}
```

connections.js ( calling from this file )

```
const createTBrowser = require("..pathTo/proxy");   
const Browser = createBrowser();
const page = await Browser.newPage();
await page.goto('Valid_URL');
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All i am looking for is a way to connect to proxy using puppeteer. 
i have tried adding arguments for ignoring self-signed cerificate error, http errors, and tried to give other proxy ip addresses like 127.0.01:9153 , etc

Answer (score 0):

The proxy is not working because the pupeteer is using a self signed cert,so
adding a ignore flag to the args might fix your problem.

```
class Proxy {
  static create() {
    return new Proxy();
  }
  
  this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
       `--proxy-server=socks5:127.0.0.1:9150`,
       "--no-sandbox",
       "--ignore-certificate-errors",
       "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list" ,
    ],
  });
  
  async newPage(newBrowser = false) {
     /* Ensure a browser instance is present */
     if (!this.browser) {
       await this.launchNewBrowser();
     }
 
     /* Close all other pages/tabs */
     await this.closePages();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried after adding the arguments. But still facing same issue.

Comment: @SardeepChabbrabluCursor Can you try telnet 127.0.0.1:9150 in your commandline? Check to see if there is a proxy which actually exists

Comment: Tried the same, Got this message :
"Connecting To 127.0.0.1:9150...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed"
I am new to this,  can you please suggest what should I do?